# show alert if checked checkbox with different attr in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, I need to check if the data-id-row values are equal to the data-id-row values of the checked table rows when the checkboxes are checked, return a value if it is equal, and a message if it is not equal. Show it.

this is my rows

```html
<table>
<thead>
   <tr>
  <th>
     <input type="checkbox" name="id[]">
  </th>
  <th>
     first name
  </th>
  <th>
     last name
  </th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr id="6">
  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>hamid</td>
  <td>hamidi</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="7">
  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>john</td>
  <td>tyler</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="8">
  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>john</td>
  <td>smith</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What are "data-id-row values" ? By the way, using brackets in name attribute like `name="id[]"`is not good idea.

Comment: @Reporter 
Assume the data-id-row is different for each checkbox
For example, 1,2,3 and now I want if the values of all selected checkboxes were equal inside the array, for example, three selected checkboxes of an array with this return value [1,1,1] should perform an operation, but if one of The values inside the array were different, ie [1,2,1] to prevent further operations.

Comment: @Reporter This is to change the status of an order list in a multi-vendor system

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will show you id's of all checked rows:

```
var trs= document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++){
var tr = trs[i];
var checks = tr.getElementsByTagName("input");
if (checks.length > 0 && checks[0].checked)
     alert(tr.id)
}
```